# Woocommerce no products were found matching your selection

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, selection, categories

> Woocommerce no products were found matching your selection

keeps popping up when I click on a category. Even when I switched theme.

HERE IS A SCREENSHOT OF ALL MY PLUGINS
https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5nsnv/samv

Comment: please attach the screenshot of the category also

Answer (score 4):

Try this ,

Go to WordPress Admin Area > WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Default Product Sorting . . . and check if it's set to
"Popularity (sales)" as in some setups this can cause issues. Try changing it to anything else and test and let me know your results for the same.

Comment: I don't know if it's changed since this answer was written, but woocommerce 4.8 has one more menu in addition to those mentioned here.  Go to WordPress Admin Area > WooCommerce > Settings > Products as you stated, but then add > Display and continue to > Default Product Sorting as you stated.  Your answer (with my small adjustment) fixed it for me.  Thanks!  Couldn't have done it without you.  Upvoted.  Perhaps someone should report this as a bug in woocommerce?

Comment: This now doesn't follow what the current version of WooCommerce is displaying (6.5.1). There are no 'Display' options when you get into Products.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes is the case that the visibility of the products is set to "hidden". To change that check the product and in the publish Metabox set the visibility to " Shop and search results"